# SUMMARIZE Table with Filtered Additional Columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking for some help with a calculated column. I have a table of repeating data that shows a GUID, a funnel step the GUID has reached, and the date it was reached.

My goal is to append two additional columns to this table, or create a new summarized table that lists the GUID, the most recent funnel step the GUID has reached, AND the most recent funnel step that GUID has reached 365 days ago. Let's assume TODAY is 11/18/2021.

Here is the starting table:

| GUID | Funnel Step | Funnel Step Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meeting Scheduled | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | Contract Signed | 10/19/2020 |
| 3 | Contract Sent | 11/17/2020 |
| 3 | Contract Signed | 11/17/2021 |

Here is the desired result:

| GUID | Most Recent Funnel Step | Most Recent Funnel Step 365 Days Ago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meeting Scheduled | NULL |
| 2 | Contract Signed | Contract Signed |
| 3 | Contract Signed | Contract Sent |

Ultimately I'm looking for any way to produce a table/matrix in PowerBI that displays a count of GUIDs for a given funnel step right now, and how that compares to last year.

Answer (score 0):

You need two measures to give you what you need

```
Most Recent Funnel Step = 
CALCULATE ( MAX ( tbl[Funnel Step] ), ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[GUID] ) )

Most Recent Funnel Step 365 Days Ago = 
VAR _1 =
    TODAY () - 365
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE (
        [Most Recent Funnel Step],
        FILTER ( tbl, tbl[Funnel Step Date] <= _1 )
    )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]